# Android Eclipse - refreshing the image in ImageView

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, refresh, onresume

I've got an image view in a certain layout that I'd like to change. I've tried to do it a couple of different ways (via .java)... but the image doesn't actually change, and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I think I'm having an issue with "refreshing" the layout to show the new image?

The XML looks like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/patientImage1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toExam"
        android:src="@drawable/cxr_ap_1"
        android:contentDescription="Sample patient picture"
        />
```

I want to switch it from the drawable cxr_ap_1.png to chestpain1ptimage.png. Here's what I do for that:

```
protected void setPtImage(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_patients_room);
        //Sets the image used for the patient icon.
        String ptImage = MainActivity.CaseBridge.GetPtImage();


        ImageView ptImageView = new ImageView(this); 
        ptImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.patientImage1); 
        int image =R.drawable.chestpain1ptimage;
        Drawable dimage = getResources().getDrawable(image);
        ptImageView.setImageDrawable(dimage);
}
```

setPtImage() is called by onResume(). I know it gets called correctly because I used some debug toast-stuff to check... but as I said, the image doesn't change.

I also tried doing:

```
int image =R.drawable.chestpain1ptimage;
ptImageView.setImageResource(image);
```

and that didn't work either. The image displayed remains cxr_ap_1.png. Help? :)

Edit: Oh. I also tried throwing in:

```
ptImageView.invalidate();
```

which is supposed to force a refresh (maybe?) but that didn't work either.

Comment: please, show me you code which is onResume()

Comment: have you tried "ptImageView .setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chestpain1ptimage));"

Comment: protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_patients_room);
  setPtImage();
  //called after you create
  //also called when user returns to this window.
  if (endPatientsRoom){
   finish();
  }
}